System.EnterpriseServices for .NET-Framework package in .NET 8.0 assembly could not be loaded
in my .NET 8.0 project, I need to run a NuGet package which was compiled for .NET-Framework. When I run the program I get an error, that file or assembly System.EnterpriseServices could not be loaded.
Following the solution presented here , I added it to the global assembly cache via VS Terminal and gacutil (but using the 4.0 framework path):
runas /user:myUser "gacutil /i C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"

Unfortunately, the error still persists. When I check the GAC using gacutil /l, I see the only line with System.EnterpriseServices is "System.EnterpriseServices.resources" (Public Key fits though)

f.e. System.Drawing has a .resources entry as well, but also the entry with no extensions.
Any idea what to do to fix the System.EnterpriseServices could not be loaded error?
Thanks in advance,
Frank

.NET 8 isn't a .NET Framework version. It's .NET Core 8, a completely different cross-platform runtime. COM+, which is wrapped by System.EnterpriseServices, is a Windows-only feature. It's not even a .NET Framework feature, the actual services and APIs are provided by Windows. BTW System.Drawing is deprecated too

The GAC is an old concept that simply died since the solution you found was still a solution. Trust 15 years old stuff only for 15 year old stuff you do and not when you try to use it in a current environment. You may want to read the NET Framework Migration Guideline. Especially the stuff that is no longer supported. If you need the EnterpriseServices stuff extract that part into its own 4.8 process and stay for that in the old world and connect via IPC mechanisms.

I see, so I probably should try to replace the .NET-Framework packages. Thanks for the advice!
